# SQL - How to SUM column with date range

Tags: sql

This is my first select. Name it as A

```
EMPLID    DATE       TIMEIN    GRACEPERIOD    NUMBER_OF_LATE
------    --------   ------    -----------    --------------
000001    1/1/2017   8:16      8:15                        1
000001    1/2/2017   8:25      8:15                        1
000001    1/3/2017   8:10      8:15                        1
000002    1/1/2017   8:30      8:15                        1
000002    1/2/2017   8:14      8:15                        0
000002    1/3/2017   8:23      8:15                        1
```

The result of sum should be like  this:

```
EMPLID    DATE                    NUMBER_OF_LATE
------    -------------------     --------------
000001    1/1/2017 - 1/3/2017                  3
000002    1/1/2017 - 1/3/2017                  2
```

I just want to group by EMPLID and will sum based on Date Range.

Comment: with EMPL_CTE(EMPLID,NO_OF_LATE,MINDATE,MAXDATE) AS ( select EMPLID,sum(NUMBER_OF_LATE)NO_OF_LATE,MIN([DATE]) MINDATE,MAX([DATE]) MAXDATE from EMPStatus where NUMBER_OF_LATE=1 group by EMPLID )  select CONVERT(nvarchar(200),[MINDATE])+' - '+CONVERT(nvarchar(200),[MAXDATE]),EMPLID,NO_OF_LATE from EMPL_CTE

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Im using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
select EMPLID, min(DATE) + ' - ' + max(DATE), sum(NUMBER_OF_LATE)
From t
group by EMPLID
```

Depending on what DBMS you are using, you might need to use a function to get your dates into the format you want.

Comment: This might not give the expected results because not all employees will have records covering the full range in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Tim - It is not very clear what OP wants. OP needs to clear what is needed.

Comment: @GurV Then why is the question being _upvoted_ while I get two downvotes?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Most of the time, the date range wouldn't even need to be present in the query, because the caller of that query would already know what the range is.

Comment: this what i am looking for. thanks guys. appreciate it

Comment: Warning: This query won't return the proper date range should a given employee be missing certain dates.

Comment: Dont worry, Date parameter will be provided from the user.

Comment: produce error in SQL-Server "*Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*"

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let us know which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

updated my answer by two different way. you can set condition after group by

```
  SELECT T1.EMPLID, MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME, T1.Date)) + ' ' + MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, T1.Date)) AS DATARANGE, 
  SUM(NUmberOfLate) AS NUMBER_OF_LATE
  FROM
      (SELECT *
         FROM AAA 
        WHERE Date BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/2017') AND CONVERT(datetime, '1/3/2018')
       ) T1
 GROUP BY T1.EMPLID


 SELECT EMPLID,
          MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME, Date)) + ' ' + MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, Date)) AS DATARANGE, 
          SUM(NUmberOfLate) AS NOF 
      FROM AAA
  GROUP BY EMPLID
```

Comment: I cant put a condition after a group by

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let us know which dbms this is for.